# Closure criterion for the convergence of sequences in a metric space

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a metric space, $z\in X$, and $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $X$.

Then according to the closure criterion for convergence of $(x_n)$ in $X$ we have that,

$$\{z\} = \bigcap\Big\{\operatorname{cl}\{x_n\mid n\in S\}\,\Big|\, S\subseteq\Bbb N\text{ and }S\text{ is infinite}\Big\}\;.$$

My question is, why is it necessary for $S$ to be infinite ?

Comment: Because for finite $S$ the closure of $\{x_n\}$ is $\{x_n\}$ itself and may not contain $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at a specific example: take $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual metric, $z=0$, and $x_n=2^{-n}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Certainly $\left\langle\frac1{2^n}:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$ converges to $0$. Let $S$ be a finite subset of $\Bbb N$; then $\{x_n:n\in S\}$ is finite. Every finite set in a metric space is closed, so $\operatorname{cl}\{x_n:n\in S\}=\{x_n:n\in S\}$, which clearly does not contain $0$. You can easily check that in this example we have

$$\bigcap\Big\{\operatorname{cl}\{x_n:n\in S\}:S\subseteq\Bbb N\Big\}=\varnothing$$

when we let $S$ range over finite as well as infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Brain M.Scott Could you please give me an example where, when S would range over infinite subsets on$\mathbb{N}$ then the intersection would be non empty ?

Comment: @johny: The same example works: if $S\subseteq\Bbb N$ is infinite, then $0\in\operatorname{cl}\{x_n:n\in S\}$, so $$\bigcap\left\{\operatorname{cl}\{x_n:n\in S\}:S\subseteq\Bbb N\text{ and }S\text{ is infinite}\right\}=\{0\}\;.$$

Comment: @M.Scott Oops! i can't believe how dumb i can be sometimes!